# Formula to round up to the next multiple not divisible by $2$ or $3$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want a formula that rounds up any integer to the next multiple of a given prime, which is not divisible by $2$ or $3$, so it is either $p$ or $5p \pmod{6p}$. The simplest formula is preferred.

I've been hacking at it with integer division and modulus operations, but haven't got anything so far that doesn't use a conditional.

I've got something working for rounding up to the next odd multiple of a prime:
$$R = i + p + i\bmod{2p} - 2(i\bmod{p})$$

I would like to extend it to rounding to the next multiple not divisible by $2$, $3$, or $5$, and then maybe generalize to not divisible by the first $n$ primes.